# How to increase the "accounts-per-user limit" in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-analytics, google-iam

When trying to give permissions to a specific User for a Google Analytics Web Site, it shows me the following Error:

> A user you tried to add is already at the accounts-per-user limit, and cannot be added to more accounts.

I'd guess, the limit is set to 1000. I have got credentials for this Service Account. But how can I increase this limit?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change the per user limit for accounts. This is a hard limitation with in Google analytics.

I would question why you were sharing that many accounts with a service account. Service accounts are meant for you to use to access an account you the developer control in order for you to access the data without the need to login.  Do you really control 1000+ different websites?

Tbh last i knew the number was 200 so the must have increased it.